# tcpdump, how to capture actual data only？

Tags: tcpdump

For example I have a server listening on port 8001, a client programe open a tcp socket connect to that port, send some binary data, I want to capture the actual data only without any TCP/IP header such as tcp handshake stuff..

Is that possible with tcpdump?

Answer (score 2):

You should run tcpflow.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpflow

```
$ sudo tcpflow port 8001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain something similar using `tcpdump -i any <your_filter> -A`. From [man tcpdump:](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html)

> -A Print each packet (minus its link level header) in ASCII. Handy for capturing web pages.

To obtain a more focused dump (ie: remove some handshake packet) you can play with the filter rules, for example removing `tcp-syn` packet from filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can capture only TCP PUSH messages by using the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-push) != 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the tcpdump haven't features to exctract payload (cut off the headers). Also the aren't any built-in features about deep analysis of application layer data. But you can write the traffic into the file, and extract the actual data with wireshark features.